# Is “someone meets something” common?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, idiomatic-language, sentence-choice, idiom-request

Three expressions:

> Someone meets someone
>
> Someone meets something
>
> Something meets someone

I can see that the first expression is commonly used by native speakers. I wonder if the second and the third are also widely use. If so, **which one of those two are mostly used** (which one is more standard)?

---

Specific Context:

> Plato meets Heraclitus
>
> Plato meets materialism
>
> Materialism meets Plato

I checked a few dictionaries including Longman, Oxford, and Idioms dictionary in which "meet with something" is a correct phrase so I am less unsure about the correctness.

I am not sure if the phrase "someone meets something" is common.

Comment: The subject of _meet_ has to be a person (or animal). People meet other people or 'meet' things (come across them for the first time), but things don't meet people.

Comment: @KateBunting I would mostly agree but sometimes *meet* is used more generally to mean "encounter", so we have examples like "What happens when an unstoppable force meets an immovable object", and it's not impossible to imagine an example like "When the movie industry met Joe Schmoe."

Comment: It's "not impossible" to imagine utterances like *When the movie industry met Joe Schmoe,* but I think that in almost all cases that "inverted" usage would be intended ***facetiously*** - implying that Joe Schmoe is of even higher status that "Mighty Muhammad" (If the mountain will not come to Muhammad, then Muhammad must go to the mountain, but the *movie industry* must go to meet Joe Schmoe, because he's too big to dance to their tune).

Comment: In music reviews, it is common to describe a band or a style as "this meets that".

Comment: @FumbleFingers What about something like: "Only hunger and fear met the refugees upon their arrival in the new country." Or with passive: "When I entered the bakery, I was met by the smell of fresh bread." Those sentences seem correct to me.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan: I wouldn't argue with either of your examples, but they're both at least *slightly* "quirky" inversions (the first one more so, imho). And whereas stangdon's "Joe Schmoe" example remains "credible" (though it'll almost always be somewhat "facetious"), I'm sure there will be many "similar" examples that are coompletely beyond the pale to many/most/all native speakers. So my advice to learners would be to *always* put the "more capable of volitional acts" entity first in these ***When Harry met Sally*** contexts.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when "something meets someone", the writer is personifying the *something*, usually to be somewhat artistic in their prose.

"The weight of the situation met Alan in that moment and worried him instantly."

Or, more plainly,

"In that moment, the weight of the situation worried Alan."

Most writers would prefer the latter.

Comment: I think for your first example, it is "something meets someone" rather than "someone meets something"?

Comment: Yes, thanks, you're right of course. Fixed it.

Comment: So, what I should learn is that "something meets someone" is uncommon while "someone meets something" is very common?